# Does a woman do Tashlumin for an omission in Prayer?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, women, mistakes, tashlumin

Is a woman obligated in Tashlumin if she makes an omission that typically requires Tashlumin, such as missing Yaaleh Veyavoh (except that of Maariv on Rosh Chodesh)?

What would the Halacha be according to those who holds women are obligated to pray Shachris and Mincha as חובה and Maariv as רשות? And what would it be according to those who would hold prayer for a woman would not be legislated to a specific time or quantity? (Mishneh Berurah 106:4 expresses both of these positions)

In other words, according to that second understanding (which I take to mean that a woman is only obligated in one Shmoneh Esreh for the day), let's say a woman makes an omission in the Shachrit Shmoneh Esreh.  She doesn't realize her omission until the afternoon.  Would she say two Minchas to make up for the omission in Shachrit or would she only say one Mincha since all she is obligated in is one Shemoneh Esreh?

Comment: Can you clarify why it is that you think that the second opinion requires a full Shemone Esrei? I see no basis for that whatsoever. In fact it seems completely wrong as (as presented in the MB and in its original context) the position was only suggested to justify those who don't say _any_ Shemone Esrei at all!

Comment: Can you clarify why you think the Halacha would be different for men and women accd to the first opinion?

Comment: The Artscroll Siddur Ohel Sarah has a section on Tashlumin (in the General Guidelines, pages XLI-XLII) but this is Tashlumin for missed davening, not erroneous davening.

Comment: I did check into this once a while ago and found it was, of course, a machlokes. I can't really remember where or who the opinions were. If you have access to the seffer Shegiyos Mi Yavin, it might have been in there.

Comment: I know R' Benzion Abba Shaul discusses this exact question in his sefer אור לציון. AFAIR he paskind that women who are committed to praying twice a day, if they miss shachris they must say Minja twice. If I'm not mistaken he discusses Ma'ariv as well since its רשות

Answer (score 2):

[Mishna Berura 263:10:43](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=75) regarding a lady who lit Shabbos candles, says can not Daven Mincha any more. If there is no time then it is better for her to Daven twice Maariv. This clearly indicates that there is Tashlumin for a woman.

Comment: This may be only a permission for tashlumin. The question is seeking a requirement.

Comment: @user6591: However you see that the lady can Daven a Reshus prayer (Maariv) and say a Tashlumin Shemona Esrei.

Comment: true. A wonderful maareh makom to be sure. But as worded, the question is still unanswered. Sorry. Not trying to nitpick.

Comment: This doesnt discuss the questions case of tashlumin due to omitting something like yaaleh veyavo

Comment: @DoubleAA Why would that be different?

Comment: @Ypnypn Maybe women aren't obligated Ad Kedei Kach when there first Shmone Esrei was valid just missing something? I don't know. It's clearly _the_ explicit subject of this question.