# Collection of laws of davenning for women?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, women

The laws of davenning for men are codified and also collected in reference volumes (e.g. [Tefillo Kehilchoso](http://www.zolsefer.co.il/171616/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%94)). Is there a sefer to study which collects the those laws  of davenning that apply to women?

By way of illustrating the question, the answer to this question: [Does a woman do Tashlumin for an omission in Prayer?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53127/does-a-woman-do-tashlumin-for-an-omission-in-prayer) was found in a section in SA O Ch dealing with candle-lighting (and not in a special sefer dealing with tefillo for women).

Related, for example: [What is a woman's obligation when it comes to T'fillah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11888/what-is-a-womans-obligation-when-it-comes-to-tfillah)

[Are women exempt from Tachanun and discouraged from saying it?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/248/are-women-exempt-from-tachanun-and-discouraged-from-saying-it/263#263)

Comment: You are mistaken. the law of women's Tashmishim was found in the regular place since their laws are the exact same as men. I don't understand what you tried to illustrate. Places where we can prove that when earlier authorities listed laws without explicitly exempting women that they meant to include women too among all Jews?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For basic Psak the simplest place is to use the well respected Halakhic work *Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayim* by R Yosef Karo about the laws of prayer for women, particularly sections 46-57 and 89-127 and 130-132 about Shacharit, 232-234 about Mincha, 237 about Maariv, and 286 about Musaf. (The material about holidays is a bit scattered in the laws of the holidays, also worth the read.) Commentaries to it are just overflowing with useful information on the subject.

For a summary of all the possible leniencies considered in the last couple hundred years to justify illiterate women of past eras not praying in accordance with the above laws, consider R Eliezer Melamed's Peninei Halakha volume entitled "Laws of Women's Prayer", available in English translation. I don't recommend most women read it cover to cover for general Halakha since while everyone should always be asking their rabbi questions and not deciding things based on books, practically it can be dangerous to have a book full of all the possible leniencies, even the extreme ones, in English on your shelf. It's certainly still Torah and has its uses, but be careful with it, using it to supplement your standard rulings in times of need.

Comment: R. Melamed’s sefer is also available online https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/category/03/

Comment: @JoelK We already knew the internet was a dangerous place! :)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10jWqdHIw_wyhlN4WRjzHfgIpsSpy-UJz/view?us%20p=sharing hasagot on r melamed tefilla

Answer (score 3):

[Halichos Bas Yisrael](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568715277) by R. Fuchs contains a section with the laws of prayer as they pertain to women.

Answer (score 2):

ArtScroll has an English translation [Women's Siddur](http://www.artscroll.com/Details.aspx?itemNo=9781422600375) which, like it's 'standard' English translation counterpart, contains an extensive 'practical laws of davening' section, with a specific focus on womens' obligations.

Comment: The section in the siddur you speak of barely sources its claims at all, I'm not sure if I'd trust it for real advice on the halacha.